# retrieve string from dynamic web table which has multiple pages : I have created code works fine but very slow

Tags: java, selenium

I'm new to selenium automation with java and i'm trying to
retrieve string from dynamic web table which has multiple pages. String displayed on 4th or 5th page but my script is very slow to fetch. Can someone help me?

WebElement nextLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]"));

```
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

                js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,10);"); 

       List<WebElement> table = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[text()='"+testID+"']"));          
                List<String> tableRows = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (WebElement rows : table) {
                tableRows.add(rows.getText());

                      if(tableRows.contains(tscID)) {

                             System.out.println(tableRows);

                             }     
                      }

                       System.out.println("===================");

                while (true) {

                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                      nextLink.click();
                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                       js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,10);");

                      table = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[text()='"+testID+"']")); 

                      for (WebElement rows : table) {

                             tableRows.add(rows.getText());

                      if(tableRows.contains(testID)) {

                             System.out.println(tableRows);
                             }     
                      }
                       System.out.println("===================");
                      try {
                      nextLink=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]"));
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                             System.out.println("Completed test for the searching TEST ID");
                             break;
                             }
                      }
```

Comment: This question is more likely to get an answer on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DebanjanB when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code would likely be closed as off-topic as it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652) - e.g. method start, `testId` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Hmmm, I should have. I simply took the bottom line, _...code works fine but very slow..._